# What is "serial voting"?

Tags: support, voting

When I clicked the "Recent achievements" button, I see an entry saying "Serial voting reversed".

What is serial voting?

Answer (score 4):

From the [Help Center](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed):

> When a single user continually votes (up or down) on many of your posts within a short period of time, this is referred to as voting fraud. This could happen for a variety of reasons, such as a user finding a user's great answer and visiting all of their posts to upvote them, or a user getting into an argument with another user and downvoting their posts indiscriminately in revenge. No matter the cause, this sort of systematic targetting voting is not considered normal behavior and the system will not allow it.

This page is linked from your reputation history; the entry that says "serial (voting, downvoting) reversed" is followed by "(learn more)".

It looks like you got a large number of downvotes in a small amount of time yesterday, so it's not surprising that this was reversed.